# Local Repo different from the one on Github

Tags: github

1) I had changed the names of the folders on my local repository. 2) Then pushed them to Github. Github thereafter created a copy of the folders with the changed names. So I have two of each folder with different folder names.

When I pull it says its up-to-date, even though there are twice as many folders on Github then on my local repo. I would like to remove the duplicates.

I read that you can't delete directories on Github. Apparently you have to do them locally and there lyes my dilemma.

[image: /Users/timurozkul/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-04-14 at 9.11.03 AM.png]

On the right is the local Repo and on the left Github.

Answer (score 1):

Your local repository may be out of date, and simply pulling the current branch will not update other branches.  To sync up, you should try doing:

```
git fetch origin
```

Most of the time, you should not have to do anything manual to keep up to date with the GitHub remote.  One exception to this would be if you somehow added/deleted folders and did not commit those changes.

Comment: When you deleted the old folders locally, did you push those changes to the remote branch?

Comment: I didn't delete anything.

Comment: You did something bad somewhere.  When you changed the folder names, your `git status` should have shown that you deleted the old folder and added a new one.  Did you see this?

Comment: ohh apparently I did delete allot of files

Comment: I'll bet you never committed those changes.  This is why GitHub still shows the old folders present.  When using Git, you should rarely have to manually step in for a situation like this.  Just use `git commit` and straighten things out.

Comment: I guess when I changed the names it deleted them and then copied them with a different folder name. Yeah I did that before and it says "Everything up-to-date"

Comment: Not quite.  Renaming a folder means deleting the old one and adding a new one.